# Computing double integral for expected value

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, physics, expected-value

Show that the mean kinetic energy for a one-dimensional particle equals $k_BT/2$. That is, show

$$E[p^2/2] =\frac{1}{Z} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{p^2}{2} e^{-\beta(V(x) + p^2/2)} \mathop{dxdp},$$

where $\beta = (k_BT)^{-1}$. I also know that

$$Z = \int_\mathbb{R^2} e^{-\beta(V(x) + p^2/2)} \mathop{dx dp}.$$

---

I just tried to expand the integral

$$E(p^2/2) = \frac{1}{Z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{p^2 e^{-\beta p^2/2}}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\beta V(x)} \mathop{dx} \mathop{dp},$$

but the innermost integral works out to be $\exp(-\beta V(x)/(-\beta V'(x))$ evaluated from $x = -\infty$ to $x = \infty$, and I'm not entirely sure how to do that. I was thinking maybe to somehow cancel out the $Z$ in the denominator with an integral but I couldn't come up with anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how does $v$ behave w.r.t $x$? Is $v(x)$ velocity of ..something?

Comment: It is potential energy, and $p^2/2$ is kinetic energy @AlvinLepik. I do not have additional information about $V(x)$.

Comment: @user7423043 : to solve the integral it is mandatory to have an expression for the function $V(x)$, i.e. $V(x)=x^2/2$

Comment: You need to control $V(x)$ so that the $x$-integral gives a finite nonzero number.  The specific form of $V$ doesn't matter --- note that the $x$-integral from $Z$ in the denominator will cancel with the $x$-integral in the numerator of $E[p^2/2]$.

Comment: This is mostly physical question. $Z$ is statistical sum - the total number of the possible particle states. If the particle has a momentum between $p$ and $p+\Delta{p}$ and a position between $x$ and $x+\Delta{x}$ the number of such states is $e^{-\beta(V(x) + p^2/2)} \Delta{x} \Delta{p}$. The average kinetic energy comes from here.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I think the problem does not require a physics background since I don't think the physics definitions aren't really important here. I know that there are other derivations of $k_BT/2$, but I would just like to compute the integral for this derivation

Comment: @user7423043 actually I think messed up the computation and it works out fine for a harmonic oscillator potential. I'll try a regularization for a free particle and see how that goes.

Comment: @user7423043   No, does not require - as soon as you add that $e^{-p^2/2}$ is the momentum distribution function (the probability density). Integration over $dx$ factorizes and can be cancelled both in the numerator and denominator of $\frac{1}{Z} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{p^2}{2} e^{-\beta(V(x) + p^2/2)} \mathop{dxdp}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Fubini's theorem to write

$$\left\langle \frac{p^2}{2} \right\rangle = \frac{\int_{\Bbb{R^2}}\frac{p^2}{2}\exp\left(-\beta(V(x)+p^2/2)\right)dxdp}{\int_{\Bbb{R^2}}\exp\left(-\beta(V(x)+p^2/2)\right)dxdp} = \frac{\left(\int_\Bbb{R}\exp\left(-\beta V(x)\right)dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_\Bbb{R}\frac{p^2}{2}\exp\left(- \frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp\right)}{\left(\int_\Bbb{R}\exp\left(-\beta V(x)\right)dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_\Bbb{R}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp\right)}$$

$$= \frac{\int_\Bbb{R}\frac{p^2}{2}\exp\left(- \frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp}{\int_\Bbb{R}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp} = \frac{\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{8\pi}{\beta^3}}}{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\beta}}} = \frac{1}{2\beta} = \frac{1}{2}k_BT$$

from Feynman's trick and the result of the Gaussian integral.

Comment: How did you go from the second equality to the third equality (i.e., how did you go from an $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ integral to the product of two $\mathbb{R}$ integrals)?

Comment: Just to clarify: When you separate the $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ integral to two $\mathbb{R}$ integrals, the second integral should be with respect to $p$, not $x$. Right? I also posted a follow-up question here in case you are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021719/computing-a-difficult-integral

Comment: @user7423043 you are correct that is a copy paste error. Factoring the integrals is a consequence of Fubini's theorem.