# Computing a difficult integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

This is actually a follow-up question to what I posted here: [Computing double integral for expected value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020071/computing-double-integral-for-expected-value). I think that the result in the previous post may be helpful in computing this integral.

The result in the previous post was:

$$\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{p^2}{2} e^{-\beta (V(x) + p^2/2)}\mathop{dx}\mathop{dp}}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} e^{-\beta (V(x) + p^2/2)} \mathop{dx}\mathop{dp}} = (k_BT)^{-1},$$

where $\beta = (k_BT)^{-1}$. So we can use this result if it makes the following integral easier.

---

I would now like to compute the following:

$$\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{6n}} \frac{p^2}{2} e^{-\beta(V(x) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^{3n} p_i^2)} \mathop{dx dp}}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{6n}} e^{-\beta(V(x) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i = 1}^{3n} p_i^2)} \mathop{dx dp}},$$

where $V$ is some unknown function of $x$. The answer should be $3nk_BT/2 = \frac{3n}{2\beta}$, but I'm really not sure about how to show this result.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where you write "dp" does that mean $dp_1 dp_2 ...dp_{3n}$? And what does the p represent in the polynomial factor out front?

Comment: *The answer should be* $3n/\beta$. Are you really sure? I would have bet $\beta^{3n}$, or $\beta^{-3n}$, referring to the previous question. The answer to the first integral doesn't correspond to the answer you got in your previous question.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Yes, it should be up to 3n. Same for $dx$. Your interpretation is correct. $p$ is $(p_1^2 + \cdots p_{3n}^2)^{1/2}$

Comment: It should be sufficient to consider the $p_1^2$ part of $p^2$, with the other parts being identical by symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the same factoring trick we can say that the $x$ integral cancels again and we are left with

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{3n}\int_\Bbb{R} \frac{p_i^2}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta p_i^2}{2}\right)dp_i \Pi_{j\neq i} \int_\Bbb{R} \exp\left(-\frac{\beta p_j^2}{2}\right)dp_j}{\left(\int_\Bbb{R} \exp\left(-\frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp\right)^{3n}}$$

$$ = \frac{3n \int_\Bbb{R} \frac{ p^2}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp \cdot \left(\int_\Bbb{R} \exp\left(-\frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp\right)^{3n-1}}{\left(\int_\Bbb{R} \exp\left(-\frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp\right)^{3n}}$$

$$= \frac{3n \int_\Bbb{R} \frac{p^2}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp}{\int_\Bbb{R} \exp\left(-\frac{\beta p^2}{2}\right)dp} = \frac{3n}{2\beta}$$

since all of the terms in the sum were identical.

Comment: @user7423043 like I said, all of the terms were identical and there were $3n$ of them. They are all $\Bbb{R^1}$

Comment: I see. I messed up the intended result actually. It is actually supposed to be $(3/2)nk_BT = \frac{3n}{2\beta}$, whereas I think your work indicates that it evaluates to $3nk_BT$. In other words, it should another factor of $\frac{1}{2}.$ Do you see anything wrong with what you posted? I've been looking but don't quite see it yet.

Comment: @user7423043 it seems I forgot a $\frac{1}{2}$ from the original integral post, which makes sense since we are proving the equipartition theorem.